# How to find the keys in dictionary object which matches partially?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, generics, dictionary

I am  trying to  grab all the items in the dictionary based on given string which matches partially or fully.

I tried the following code  but doesn't seems to work

```
a.Where(d => d.Value.Contains(text)).ToDictionary(d => d.Key, d => d.Value);
```

Can you please tell me how to achieve this ?

Comment: Can you please define "but doesn't seems to work"? What happens? Does it explode in sparks? does it give empty results? Please assume that we need to know what you are experiencing, and how this differs from your expectation (so please tell us what you expected, too).

Comment: Your question is unclear. In the title it says find the *keys*, but your code is checking the *values*. Perhaps you meant `d => d.Key.Contains(text)`??

Comment: I would expect this to be kind of slow; it probably has to iterate over every key entry, negating the value of the Dictionary in this use case.  Hopefully you don't have to do this often, or else you might need a different data structure (if you have a lot of entries).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code you've given should work absolutely fine, assuming you really wanted to find *entries* where the *value* had a partial match. If you're seeing something else, I suspect your diagnostics are flawed. If you wanted to find entries where the *key* had a partial match, you just want to swap

```
a.Where(d => d.Value.Contains(text))
```

for

```
a.Where(d => d.Key.Contains(text))
```

Short but complete program demonstrating the code you've given working:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var original = new Dictionary<string, string> {
            { "a", "foo" },
            { "b", "bar" },
            { "c", "good" },
            { "d", "bad" },
        };

        string needle = "oo";

        var filtered = original.Where(d => d.Value.Contains(needle))
                               .ToDictionary(d => d.Key, d => d.Value);

        foreach (var pair in filtered)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} => {1}", pair.Key, pair.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
a => foo
c => good
```